# fpdf2 error Invalid value for parameter "new_x"

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Tutorial.html), specifically the *Tuto 2*, but I keep getting the following error and I don't know why. I copied and pasted the code from the tutorial. I'm on version 2.5.2.

> ValueError: Invalid value for parameter "new_x" (0),must be instance
> of Enum XPos

```
from fpdf import FPDF

class PDF(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        # Rendering logo:
        self.image("logo.png", 10, 8, 33)
        # Setting font: helvetica bold 15
        self.set_font("helvetica", "B", 15)
        # Moving cursor to the right:
        self.cell(80)
        # Printing title:
        self.cell(30, 10, "Title", 1, 0, "C")
        # Performing a line break:
        self.ln(20)

    def footer(self):
        # Position cursor at 1.5 cm from bottom:
        self.set_y(-15)
        # Setting font: helvetica italic 8
        self.set_font("helvetica", "I", 8)
        # Printing page number:
        self.cell(0, 10, f"Page {self.page_no()}/{{nb}}", 0, 0, "C")


# Instantiation of inherited class
pdf = PDF()
pdf.alias_nb_pages()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Times", size=12)
for i in range(1, 41):
    pdf.cell(0, 10, f"Printing line number {i}", 0, 1)
pdf.output("tuto2.pdf")
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the [github project](https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/blob/master/fpdf/fpdf.py) indicates that you need to be passing in an XPos and YPos object for `new_x` and `new_y`.

First, add this right below your import statement:

`from fpdf.enums import XPos, YPos`.

This will bring in the classes you need to correctly set the position of the page number.

Then update the `footer` function - instead of

`self.cell(0, 10, f"Page {self.page_no()}/{{nb}}", 0, 0, "C")`, use

`self.cell(0, 10, f"Page {self.page_no()}/{{nb}}", XPos.RIGHT, new_y=YPos.NEXT, "C")`.